# neo4j- connection to database

Tags: spring, maven, neo4j

I'm new with neo4j and spring boot/ spring mvc. I try to understand the movie graph database from neo4j.com and I build in the same way a new database and the app,but when i run the "localhost:8080" it loads only the structure of html file that i created. I can't bring data from database on the http page.

This is main class:

```
package companie.neo4j;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;

//import companie.spring.data.neo4j.SampleCompanyApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan("companie.spring.data.neo4j.domain")
public class SampleCompanyApplication {


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(SampleCompanyApplication.class, args);
        }
    }
```

Controller:

```
package companie.spring.data.neo4j.controller;

import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import companie.spring.data.neo4j.services.ProjectService;
@RestController("/")
public class ProjectController {


        final ProjectService projectService;

        @Autowired
        public ProjectController(ProjectService projectService) {
            this.projectService = projectService;
        }

        @RequestMapping("/graph")
        public Map<String, Object> graph(@RequestParam(value = "limit",required = false) Integer limit) {
            return projectService.graph(limit == null ? 100 : limit);
        }
}
```

ProgrammerRepository:

```
package companie.spring.data.neo4j.repositories;

import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import companie.spring.data.neo4j.domain.Programmer;


public interface ProgrammerRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Programmer,Long> {

}
```

ProjectRepository:

```
package companie.spring.data.neo4j.repositories;

import java.util.Collection;

import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;

import companie.spring.data.neo4j.domain.Project;

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "project", path = "project")

public interface ProjectRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Project, Long>  {
    Project findByTitle(@Param("title") String title);
    Collection<Project> findByTitleLike(@Param("title") String title);


    @Query("MATCH (proj:Project)<-[r:IMPLEMENTED]-(progr:Person) RETURN proj,r,progr LIMIT {limit}")
    Collection<Project> graph(@Param("limit") int limit);

}
```

ProjectService:

```
package companie.spring.data.neo4j.services;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import companie.spring.data.neo4j.domain.Programmer;
import companie.spring.data.neo4j.domain.Project;
import companie.spring.data.neo4j.repositories.ProjectRepository;
import companie.spring.data.neo4j.domain.Project;
import companie.spring.data.neo4j.domain.Programmer;
import companie.spring.data.neo4j.repositories.ProjectRepository;

@Service
public class ProjectService {
    @Autowired ProjectRepository projectRepository;

    private Map<String, Object> toD3Format(Collection<Project> projects) {
        List<Map<String, Object>> nodes = new ArrayList();
        List<Map<String, Object>> rels = new ArrayList();
        int i = 0;
        Iterator<Project> result = projects.iterator();
        while (result.hasNext()) {
            Project project = result.next();
            nodes.add(map("title",project.getTitle(), "label", "project"));
            int target = i;
            i++;
            for (Programmer p : project.getProgrammer() ) {
                Map<String, Object> coder = map("title", p.getName(), "label", "coder");
                int source = nodes.indexOf(coder);
                if (source == -1) {
                    nodes.add(coder);
                    source = i++;
                }
                rels.add(map("source", source, "target", target));
            }
        }
        return map("nodes", nodes, "links", rels);
    }

    private Map<String, Object> map(String key1, Object value1, String key2, Object value2) {
        Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>(2);
        result.put(key1, value1);
        result.put(key2, value2);
        return result;
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Map<String, Object>  graph(int limit) {
        Collection<Project> result = projectRepository.graph(limit);
        return toD3Format(result);
    }
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Company</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="graph">
</div>
<div role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <form role="search" class="navbar-form" id="search">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" value="JAVAPROJECT" placeholder="Search for Project Title" class="form-control" name="search">
                            </div>
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Search</button>
                        </form>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-header col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="logo-well">
                    <a href="http://neo4j.com/developer-resources">
                        <img src="http://neo4j-contrib.github.io/developer-resources/language-guides/assets/img/logo-white.svg" alt="Neo4j World's Leading Graph Database" id="logo">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-brand">
                    <div class="brand">Neo4j Company</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Search Results</div>
            <table id="results" class="table table-striped table-hover">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Project</th>
                    <th>TITLE</th>
                    <th>YEAR</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" id="title">Details</div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                    <img src="" class="well" id="poster"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
                    <h4>Programmers</h4>
                    <ul id="programmers">
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<style type="text/css">
    .node { stroke: #222; stroke-width: 1.5px; }
    .node.actor { fill: #888; }
    .node.movie { fill: #BBB; }
    .link { stroke: #999; stroke-opacity: .6; stroke-width: 1px; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        function showProject(title) {
            $.get("/project/search/findByTitle?title=" + encodeURIComponent(title), // todo fix paramter in SDN
                    function (data) {
                        if (!data ) return; //  || !data["_embedded"].project) return;
                        var project = data; // ["_embedded"].project[0];
                        $("#title").text(project.title);
                        $("#poster").attr("src","http://neo4j-contrib.github.io/developer-resources/language-guides/assets/posters/"+encodeURIComponent(project.title)+".jpg");
                        var $list = $("#programmers").empty();
                        project.programmer.forEach(function (cast) {
                            $.get(cast._links.programmer.href, function(programmerData) {
                                var programmer = programmerData.name;
                                //var job = cast.job || "IMPLEMENTED";
                                $list.append($("<li>" + programmer + "</li>"));
                            });
                        });
                    }, "json");
            return false;
        }
        function search() {
            var query=$("#search").find("input[name=search]").val();
            $.get("/project/search/findByTitleLike?title=*" + encodeURIComponent(query) + "*",
                    function (data) {
                        var t = $("table#results tbody").empty();
                        if (!data) return;
                        data = data["_embedded"].projects;
                        data.forEach(function (project) {
                            $("<tr><td class='project'>" + project.title + "</td><td>" + project.year + "</td></tr>").appendTo(t)
                                    .click(function() { showProject($(this).find("td.project").text());})
                        });
                        showProject(data[0].title);
                    }, "json");
            return false;
        }

        $("#search").submit(search);
        search();
    })
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var width = 800, height = 800;

    var force = d3.layout.force()
            .charge(-200).linkDistance(30).size([width, height]);

    var svg = d3.select("#graph").append("svg")
            .attr("width", "100%").attr("height", "100%")
            .attr("pointer-events", "all");

    d3.json("/graph", function(error, graph) {
        if (error) return;

        force.nodes(graph.nodes).links(graph.links).start();

        var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
                .data(graph.links).enter()
                .append("line").attr("class", "link");

        var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
                .data(graph.nodes).enter()
                .append("circle")
                .attr("class", function (d) { return "node "+d.label })
                .attr("r", 10)
                .call(force.drag);

        // html title attribute
        node.append("title")
                .text(function (d) { return d.title; })

        // force feed algo ticks
        force.on("tick", function() {
            link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
                    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
                    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
                    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

            node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
                    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.neo4j.companie</groupId>
  <artifactId>neo4j-companie</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Neo4j Companie</name>
  <description>Web project for Spring Boot using Spring Data Neo4j</description>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>

  </parent>

   <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <neo4j-ogm.version>2.1.2</neo4j-ogm.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId> org.springframework.data </groupId>
   <artifactId> spring-data-neo4j </artifactId>
   <version> 3.1.2.RELEASE </version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver</artifactId>
            <version>${neo4j-ogm.version}</version>
        </dependency>

     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

  <!-- For use in testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-embedded-driver</artifactId>
            <version>${neo4j-ogm.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
   <groupId> javax.transaction </groupId>
   <artifactId> jta </artifactId>
   <version> 1.1 </version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId> javax.validation </groupId>
   <artifactId> validation-api </artifactId>
   <version> 1.0.0.GA </version>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Thank you!!

Comment: does your controller and servie classes getting called?  did you put a breakpoint and check?

Comment: I tried to use breakpoint, but he brings  many dependences from the internet and it is used also annotation.